# How can I restore my database data with only postgres dump on heroku

Tags: django, postgresql, heroku, heroku-postgres, pg-dump

I reached to the build limit on my heroku app while there was a lot changes I still wanted to make and I came up with the tought of creating another app and use the same database as the first app and thereafter delete the first app and rename the second app I created to the deleted first app's name but when I deleted the first app I ran into an issue database was also deleted but before deleting that app I downloaded postgres dump for backup so now I uploaded it to my github to just restore my data.

And now I'm running the following command

```
heroku pg:backups:restore 'https://github.com/myusername/repo/path/branch/latest.dump' --app myappname --c
onfirm myappname
```

but I'm getting the following error

```
Restoring... !
 !    An error occurred and the backup did not finish.
 !
 !    waiting for restore to complete
 !    pg_restore finished with errors
 !    waiting for download to complete
 !    download finished with errors
 !    please check the source URL and ensure it is publicly accessible
 !
```

So I want to know if there is anything I can do to perfome backup or I'm just wasted, realy need your help

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are using an incorrect URL to point the dump file,

`https://github.com/myusername/repo/path/branch/latest.dump` is a blob_url which is like a URL of the web page, we get a rendered HTML version of the file by accessing the blob_url.

You should use a raw_url to point the dumb file, to get the raw_url click on the **Raw** button on the blob page of the respected file

[image: github get raw file link]

Hope that should work